# Ubuntu 22.04 not shutdown

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

Can someone help me? When I turn off my computer, it just turns off the monitor screen, but the monitor light is still on, considering that my computer is an all-in-one, I always need to force the power off, so I can turn it on again later.

Some useful information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.19.0-43-generic
CPU: Intel Celeron N2808 (2) @ 2.249
GPU: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37
Memory: 1865MiB / 3811MiB

System Information
Manufacturer: Positivo Informatica SA
Product Name: DH8BT11TV
Version: 1.02.U
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include your computer's make/model, as that will help in diagnosing your issue. Also, to confirm, are you certain that you're actually powering down your computer, or putting it to sleep (suspend mode)?

Comment: I believe so, it is turning off instead of suspending it. If you want to see the logs after turning off the computer, see this link: https://paste.linux.chat/?f1b4db98f0081b50#HXmt1wQHNoh62C13iDMpSvSxeTEKgnVghumb3bhnxLva. I edited the thread with the information mentioned. Thank you very much!